# Spam flag on removed answer

Tags: discussion

I flagged an answer from a review queue, either First Answer or New Answer on Old Question.  Within an hour, the answer was removed, and a moderator declined my flag.  Is there no way of noting removed answers?  Should a flag automatically disappear with removed posts?

[Old Question with New, Removed Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180785/angular-js-truncate-text-and-add-read-more/40191454#40191454)
[image]

Comment: You get the priviledge to see deleted answers at 10k. Otherwise I'm not clearly understand what you're asking about.

Comment: Jerry, please [edit] the post to clarify if you just interested to know what happened/ why spam flag was declined or you have some other question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I am learning the flagging system, I thought that answer in those circumstances was very suspiciously spam, and wondered why moderator declined.  Now I know that spam flags carry more weight.  I suppose the system worked as expected.

Comment: As others have already said, this *post* is spammy (very spammy), but the spam flag was probably found invalid due to the user's history. But I'd like to add still that I believe moderators have an option to dispute spam flags (rather than declining them) in such cases. I'd argue that this would probably have been the most proper course of action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That poster has posted a question with the same text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109263/read-more-button-issue-in-angular-js. The link appears to be relevant to their problem, and not spam, even though the phrasing of the post is typical for spam.

They didn't get any answer to their question, so they decided to re-post it as an answer to an existing question. A "Not An Answer" flag would have done the trick.

Because of the penalties that come with a spam flag, moderators won't apply them lightly. If you suspect a post to be spam, take a look at the poster's profile to discover whether they're actually trying to spam, or perhaps just don't speak English that well.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation.  As a follow-up, what is the difference between flagging as Spam or Not An Answer?

Comment: A spam flag has more impact, reduces reputation and whatnot.

Comment: @Jerry Spam flag is for actual advertisements of products/services/... I'd mark that as spam too - but looks like instead one should have looked at user's posts first and it would be clear that it is just NAA.

Comment: @CodeCaster may be a good idea to suggest steps one should have taken to decide between spam/NAA/custom flagging (I'd flag as spam).

Comment: I thought the point of flagging as spam was to get the content purged as soon as possible. If ordinary users are taking all this time to research a user's history, it will add more time between spam posting and flagging. It's up to the moderators to take a look at the user's history and validate its "spamminess".

Comment: @Mike in case of obvious spam, yeah. I hope you're not suggesting flagging anything as spam that looks unintelligible.

Comment: @CodeCaster Nope, but the answer in question here looks to me like spam (user has one rep point, long URL, a company with Viral in its name), and I'm wondering about whether it's a good idea to have people take the time to search the histories of other users instead of just flagging. Seems like the moderator in this case could have overridden the default and marked the flag as helpful, but still deleted the content.